# How to rotate element to left and right based on mouse movement using jQuery & CSS

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, mousemove

I have a fixed width element in the middle of the screen, absolute positioned:

```
div {
    width:50px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-100px -25px;
    background:red;
}
```

When the cursor is in the middle of the screen, i want to display the above div completely straight. When i move the cursor to the left of the screen, i want to rotate the div to the left by 20 degrees, and the same goes to the right side too. This is what i got so far:

```
var bodywidth = $("body").width();
function mouse(evt) {

    //getting mouse dimentions
    var pageX = event.pageX;                
    var now = bodywidth / pageX;

    $("div").css({
        transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
    });

}
$("body").mousemove(mouse);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rsog7e6f/

Any tips on how to proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var now = 40 * pageX / bodywidth - 20;
```

This should answer your question.

[Codepen because Jsfiddle acts weird here](http://codepen.io/Logo/pen/myyNMQ)

Answer (score 1):

You need to map half of the body with to a value between 0 and 180

```
function mapWidthToDegs(x,w) {
    var factor = 180/(w/2);
    return factor * x - w
}
```

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLr371b5/1/)